# Selecting rows with primary key field = null

Tags: python, django

I have this code:

```
object_id = request.POST.get('id')
try:
    object = request.user.object_set.get(id=object_id, flag=False)
except Object.DoesNotExist:
    object = None
```

I thought if `object_id == None`, I will always get `object == None`. But no! When `object_id` is None I get some `object` from DB! I used remote debugging and checked that first time I evaluate `request.user.object_set.get(id=object_id, flag=False)` I got Object instance, and second time I evaluate this code I got DoesNotExist exception.

I rewrote this code to explicitly check `object_id` and only then ask DB to get object. I'm just curious - why this could happen? Some cache issue? Also small note - it works as expected on local machine (Windows 7), it doesn't work only on the server (CentOS), but the same version of Python/Django.

Comment: Check the DB what primary key it has for this record. Maybe None was not mapped to NULL properly, but is a 0 or the word "None" or something like that.

Comment: primary key field can't be null. If you talking about the table is empty,then,it won't return any row either.Yeah still,if you want to select any row with value NULL ,then you need to use `value is NULL`.You can't use `value = NULL`.Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Table is not empty, all IDs are positive integers (1..30). I looked at SQL and it was "WHERE id IS NULL" - seems correct. I think it could be connected only with Django somehow...

Answer (score 1):

maybe your post data isnt sending as expected. Try printing object_id when running the python code and see what you got. you should really consider making all PK's as NOT NULL in your database configuration. To search for null values, None should do it

try setting a default value to your post data

```
object_id = request.POST.get('id', None)
```

Comment: I checked, my `object_id` was None. Interesting thing - while `object_id` is None, selected object had id like 2 or 3 - positive integer! Bad magic.

Comment: What django version and what DB backend are you using ? I just tried a similar querie in one of my projects and got the expected result (ObjectDoesNotExist exception).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, 1.3, MySQL. I think we can't find the reason now - I changed code on server and I can't reproduce it locally. Thanks for help.